# Reverse Engineering a Binary to reset a BIOS password

Tags: binary, bios

I have a laptop that I recently lost the BIOS Admin password for. I contacted the manufacturer and, after giving them some information about my BIOS (version, uuid), they sent me a file, `smc.bin` to put on a USB stick and boot in order to reset the BIOS password.

I'm interested in how this works and what the binary file is. I'm skilled with linux, but don't know much about reverse-engineering. What tools can I use to examine this binary? What's a introductory thought-process to determine what a binary file like this is?

Answer (score 5):

As a tool I would recommend [radare2](https://github.com/radare/radare2) for this task.

And if you never done something like this before [this](https://sites.google.com/site/pinczakko/pinczakko-s-guide-to-award-bios-reverse-engineering) is probably the best tutorial to get you started with.

Just be in mind its not gonna be a quick and dirty job, might take you a while.

Comment: That tutorial is for the legacy BIOSes. Modern PC/Laptops firmware usually UEFI-based.

Answer (score 2):

What vendor do you have? If it is UEFI-compatible firmware, you can use [UEFITool](https://github.com/LongSoft/UEFITool) to unpack it.
And use the [radare2](https://github.com/radare/radare2) tool to disassemble the code.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually knowing more about the system (system vendor), I would suggest to use `binwalk` to get the basic file layout. Then follow what other have done:

- [Reverse Engineering Bios Firmware](https://www.reddit.com/r/ReverseEngineering/comments/2a6uyk/reverse_engineering_bios_firmware/)
- [Extract Samsung BIOS WPH](http://www.richud.com/wiki/Extract_Samsung_BIOS_WPH)

You may want to use [hachoir / hachoir-subfile](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/hachoir-subfile), see for example:

- https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/9357/3041